# How can I get the href in a <a class in Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get a href from a webpage with selenium. When I use the browser console with following javascript command I get the right href:
`document.getElementsByClassName('item-panel__title')[0].getAttribute('href')`

Using Selenium trying to do the same, looking like this:

`handle_browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'item-panel__title')[0].getattr('href')`

I get the error code:

`AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getattr'`

The HTML code:

```html
<a class="item-panel__title" href="/u/abcd" rel="">@abcd</a>
<div class="item-panel__description">abcd</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting web element attribute value with Selenium in Python is done with `get_attribute()` method.
So, instead of `handle_browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'item-panel__title')[0].getattr('href')`
try using

```py
handle_browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'item-panel__title')[0].get_attribute('href')
```

Also, since you are getting from the first element in the list of possible matchings, you can use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`, as following:

```py
handle_browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'item-panel__title').get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: That solved my Problem. Can you recommend any documentation I could read?

Comment: What documentation are you looking for?